# How to override the Admin Invoice controller

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to override the admin sales/order/invoice controller. I tried everything but it does not override. Below is the code:

Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <config>
    <admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <use>admin</use>     
            <args>
                <modules><TW_Printinvoice before="Mage_Adminhtml">TW_Printinvoice_Adminhtml</TW_Printinvoice>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Controller File with path: `app/code/local/TW/Printinvoice/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/`

```
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/InvoiceController.php';
class TW_Printinvoice_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_PrintController extends    Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController
{
    public function printAction()
    {
        die('Testing'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code in controller file. **InvoiceController.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/InvoiceController.php';
class TW_Printinvoice_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController
{
    public function printAction()
    {
        die('Testing'); 
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: Thanks this worked for me .. but don't know why the file name makes the difference ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this config:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <TW_Printinvoice  before="Mage_Adminhtml">TW_Printinvoice_Adminhtml_Sales_Order</TW_Printinvoice >
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```